# getting pivot table in pandas in the desired format

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe

```
Categories                     Owner
Product_Query                   products_team                   
Product_Query                   products_team
Infrastructure_Query            infra_team
Bug_Query                      development_team
Bug_Query                       development_team
```

I want to display the above data in the following format

```
Categories             Total    products_team    infra_team   development_team  
Product_Query              2        2                 0           0                                     
Infrastructure_Query       1        0                  1          0                                 
Bug_Query                  2        0                  0          2
```

I am doing the following

```
df["count"]=1

df_pivot=df.pivot_table(index=["Catagories"],columns=["Owner"],values=["count"],aggfunc=[np.sum],fill_value=0)
```

But I am not getting the output in the correct format.How can I get the output in the format mentioned above?

Comment: The only real issue you have is that you specify everything as a list, so it creates unnecessary levels in your column axis. If you instead use the arguments: `index="Categories", columns="Owner", values="count", aggfunc=np.sum,` you'll basically get exactly what you want (minus the total column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can try using `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Categories'], df['Owner'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
```

Output:

```
Owner                 development_team  infra_team  products_team  Total
Categories                                                              
Bug_Query                            2           0              0      2
Infrastructure_Query                 0           1              0      1
Product_Query                        0           0              2      2
Total                                2           1              2      5
```

And, if you don't want the row Total you can drop it:

```
df_out = pd.crosstab(df['Categories'], df['Owner'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')
df_out = df_out.drop('Total')
df_out
```

Output:

```
Owner                 development_team  infra_team  products_team  Total
Categories                                                              
Bug_Query                            2           0              0      2
Infrastructure_Query                 0           1              0      1
Product_Query                        0           0              2      2
```

---

## Or using `pivot_table`:

```
df.assign(counts=1)\
  .pivot_table('counts','Categories','Owner','sum', 
               fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='Total')\
  .drop('Total')
```

Output:

```
Owner                 development_team  infra_team  products_team  Total
Categories                                                              
Bug_Query                            2           0              0      2
Infrastructure_Query                 0           1              0      1
Product_Query                        0           0              2      2
```

---

## Or using `groupby`:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['Categories', 'Owner'])['Owner'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
df_out['Total'] = df_out.sum(1)
```

Output:

```
Owner                 development_team  infra_team  products_team  Total
Categories                                                              
Bug_Query                            2           0              0      2
Infrastructure_Query                 0           1              0      1
Product_Query                        0           0              2      2
```